# Geodesics of the complex projective space

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, projective-space, geodesic

Is the complex projective space, a geodesic space?

Is the complex projective space, a convex space?

Let H be hyperplane of $\mathbb{C} P^n$, Is $\mathbb{C} P^n\setminus H,$ a bounded convex space?

Comment: ? What is your definition of a geodesic space here? Do you mean that it is a manifold where any two points are the endpoints of some geodesic? In that case, this quickly follows from the Riemannian structure.

Comment: You need to provide context and proof attempts if you would like any help though. This is not a site to get help on homework questions if you're not willing to put in the effort.